# How do i alter the content of an iframe in the dom using firefox extension code?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I would like to alter the page shown in my browser using a **firefox extension** (add-on) i wrote.
I am able to get the page's iframes as **XPCNativeWrapper** object using:

```
iframes = window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')

for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
  var elmInput = iframes[i];
  Firebug.Console.log(elmInput);
}
```

But i haven't been able to get to the iframes content, not speaking of altering it.

**How can  i alter the content of an iframe in the dom?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `elmInput.contentDocument`

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < iframes.length; i++) {
    var content = iframes[i].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
    ...
}
```